# php web-driver : how to to click a button on a popup page

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I wana click on a submit button on a popup page using php web-driver. When I click on a button, its open a boostrap confirmation popup, Now I tying to click on button on this popup.Like this .

[image: page_popup]

When I use xpath for locate this button. its getting below error.

```
ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:02:37'
System info: host: 'DSS-405', ip: '172.16.12.130', os.name: 'Windows 8', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.2', java.versi
on: '1.7.0_07'
```

I'm new in web-driver scripting. Please anybody help me.

**Update Code snapshot**

```
    class LoginTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    /**
     * @var \RemoteWebDriver
     */
    protected $webDriver;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $capabilities = array(\WebDriverCapabilityType::BROWSER_NAME => 'firefox');
        $this->webDriver = RemoteWebDriver::create('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', $capabilities);
    }

    protected $url = 'http://mywebsite.com/user.html';

    public function testLogin() {

        $this->webDriver->get($this->url);

        $confirmBtn  = $this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath('//*[@id="userCommand"]/div[2]/div[2]/button')) ;

        $confirmBtn->click();

    }
?>
```

Comment: can anyone with `php` skills convert my answer for OP?

Comment: can u try with absolute xpath. It seems to be in a modal frame or so. It would be great if u could share html snippet of the webpage.

Answer (score 1):

Try to wait until the button is clickable.

```
public function testLogin() {

    $this->webDriver->get($this->url);

    $confirmBtn = $this->webDriver->wait()->until(
        WebDriverExpectedCondition::elementToBeClickable(
            WebDriverBy::xpath('//*[@id="userCommand"]/div[2]/div[2]/button')
        )
    );

    $confirmBtn->click();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
driver.switchTo().activeElement() //java code. But should be easy to convert
```

and then find the *cancel* or *agree* button and click. Be sure to provide necessary wait for the confirmation pop up to appear.

Comment: Sorry, Can you please explain more. I don't understand.

Comment: Is it possible to provide your code snippet? So that I can modify/add and explain. I am not sure how are you instantiating the driver.

Comment: After performing some action that makes the confirmation box pops up appear. You still need to perform that action(click or whatever) then use my code to set focus on active element which in this case is the `bootstrap confirmation box`. After click use some wait so that the program has some wait for the confirmation to appear. then find find close or agree with xpath or css or whatever and click

Comment: Sorry I am not a `php` expert but looked for php selenium api doc. Is there any? I cannot find any

Answer (score -2):

Did you tried, driver.switchTo().alert?

Below is the Syntax is Java:

```
Alert alert=driver.switchTo().alert().
alert.accept() //for accepting the conformation message.
alert.dismiss() //for cancelling the conformation message.
```